# ASP.NET MVC with Castle Logging and log4net woes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, log4net

In my installer, I have

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net("log4net.config"));
}
```

My log4net config file (which gets deployed to the bin directory of my ASP.NET MVC app) is:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=GCO06773\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=GEMS;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=<<userid removed>>;Password=<<password removed>>#" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
 </root>
</log4net>
```

I have a controller that's instantiated via Castle.Windsor The relevant code is:

```
public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Logger.Info("Info");
    Logger.Debug("Debug");
    Logger.Error("Error");
    Logger.Fatal("Fatal");
    Logger.Warn("Warn");
    return View();
}
```

The Logger is a valid castle logger and when I delve into it in the watch window, it appears that there are no appenders associated with the underlying log4net logger, except for the root appender.

According to procmon, the log4net.config file is actually being accessed at some point, so I'm assuming it's being read. I get no errors in the IIS log, no errors in the event log and no exceptions or errors that I can detect. I'm stumped.

UPDATE 1:
Forgot to mention, I added this:

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config"/>
```

to the web.config, but it didn't seem to change anything.

UPDATE 2:

I'm using Log4Net 1.2.10.0 with public key token: 1b44e1d426115821 (this matters with Castle Logging which is why I mention it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `log4net.config` file should be in root of your web, not in `bin` directory.

Comment: I had actually tried that, but I guess that maybe I failed to restart the site, so the change didn't get picked up. Thanks. That fixed it.